# Creating a lme4 multilevel model based off a lavaan structural equation model with latent regression

Tags: r, lme4, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model, brms

## Background

I am trying to convert a `lavaan` structural equation model into an `lmer` multi-level item response model. The model has 2 latent factors measured by 3 variables apiece. One of the latent factors is regressed on the other latent factor and a group-level, time-invariant, exogenous covariate ("sex").

## Issue

Can someone advise on how to build in the regressions between the latent variables in the SEM into the multilevel model? In the minimal working example below, I fit the `lavaan` model and try to implement a hierarchical version of it in `lmer` but cannot figure out how to add the latent regression.

## Working Example

### Prepare data for `lme4` and `lavaan`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lavaan)
library(lme4)
library(semPlot)

# Load, keep variables in model, drop NAs and normalize all latent variable 
# indicators then let all measures of lv2 be continuous and all measures of
# lv1 be ordinal
dat <- lavaan::HolzingerSwineford1939 %>%
  select(starts_with("x") | sex) %>%
  select(-c("x7","x8","x9")) %>%
  mutate(sex = sex - 2) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("x"), ~ scale(.x))) %>%
  mutate(across(c(paste0("x", 1:3)),
                ~ case_when(. < -0.5 ~ 1,
                            . >= -0.5 &
                              . < 0.5 ~ 2,
                            . >= 0.5 ~ 3))) %>%
  na.omit()

# Prepare data for 1 pl multilevel item response model
# Convert to long format: each row is an item response add indicators for the latent factor that item loads onto and a variable with the nominal
# category for that variable
dat_irt <- dat %>% mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "item", 
               cols = starts_with("x"), 
               values_to = "response") %>%
  mutate(lv1_item = case_when(item %in% paste0("x",1:3) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
         lv2_item = case_when(item %in% paste0("x",4:6) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
         item_type = case_when(lv1_item == 1 ~ "lv1", TRUE ~ "lv2"))
```

## `lavaan` Model

```r
m1 <- 'lv1 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
       lv2 =~ x4 + x5 + x6
       lv2 ~ lv1 + sex'

m1_out <- lavaan::sem(model = m1, data = dat) 

# Look at path diagram and model output
m1_out %>% semPaths()
```

[image]

## `lme4` Hierarchical Model

```r
# Fit 1-factor  Rasch (1-pl) model
dat_irt %>% lme4::lmer(response ~ -1 + item + (1 | id), .) %>% summary()

# Now "regress" lv1 on lv2...as best as I can tell, this produces an ability
# estimate for each id (person) but I don't see how that's a "regression" 
dat_irt %>% lme4::lmer(response ~ -1 + item  + (-1 + item_type | id), .) %>% summary()

# Finally add time-invariant, exogenous, binary, id-level "sex"  covariate...
# no idea where to add this since I only want it to predict lv2!
dat_irt %>% lme4::lmer(response ~ -1 + item  + sex  + (-1 + sex + item_type | id), .) %>% summary()
```

Comment: afaik, you can only specify a mixed-effects model that is equivalent to a CFA (with parallel-indicator constraints).  Regressing a common factor on another common factor is analogous to regressing random effects on each other, which is not a feature of any standard mixed-effects modeling packages I am aware of (unless the superbeast MLwiN can do something like this?). You could certainly do so in a Bayesian hierarchical model, using flexible software like Stan or JAGS.

Comment: @Terrence Yes, I was using `lme4` to see if anyone had any ideas that would let me use `brms`. Maybe this could be done in `brms` with the non-linear capabilities https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_nonlinear.html but I'm not sure what actual model is specified with those arguments. I'll probably adapt what is done in this code in rstan https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/multi-group-confirmatory-factor-analysis-how-to-handle-the-cholesky-factor-correlations/12687/2  to (a) specify a regression coefficient not a correlation (i.e. add a mean) and (b) include a predictor.